# Generate Near Table causes ArcMap shutdown

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, proximity

When I try to find the distances from xy coordinates to linear landforms such as roads and rivers, using Generate Near Table, it keeps shutting arcmap down and sending error reports, without telling me what I have been doing wrong? 
Does anyone know a way around this? Or what I am doing wrong? I'm pretty certain that generate near table is the only way to get the data that I need.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS do you work with? Do you use several feature classes as Near features?

Comment: Are the datasets in the same projection? If they are very large, try working on a subset of the data, to narrow down what is going wrong.